# How to paginate ElasticSearch index names?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 1000 indexes (not index documents, but indexes) in my ElasticSearch cluster. 
How do I paginate them to show 20 indexes on a page? I obviously cant show all 1000 on the page. I have searched, but could not find any info on that case.

Also it does not let me pass `from` as a parameter or `limit` when requesting info on all indexes.

Comment: What you mean it _dosen't let me_?

Comment: @ARMAN those parameters are not optional for the method.

Answer (score 0):

There's no pagination option for [listing incdices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/cat-indices.html) in elastic.

The [from/size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-from-size) parameters are for using the [search api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html) only.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if your showing them in client facing GUI then you're going to have to implement pagination logic yourself (which honestly should not be hard).

Comment: I am sure it should not be hard, if there is a way to limit the output, and iterate over it. But I cant find how to do that :/

Comment: are there any similar parameters that can be passed to listing indices?

Comment: the problem is taht I have 5k+ indexes and don't want to fetch them all.